# How to pass parameter to a DataRow

Tags: c#, linq

I have a very peculiar problem, I am filtering a table according to a range of dates, and everything works fine when the column number is specified directly, but in the absence of this method. , since, I get that "The specified conversion is not valid". I do not know if the sea is a code problem or is a LINQ's bug. I leave the two cases.

works ok:

```
public DataTable GetTableByDate(DataTable table, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int columnNumber)
    {
        var filteredRows = from row in table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                           where (DateTime)row[1] > startDate 
                           where (DateTime)row[1] <= endDate select row;
        var filteredTable = table.Clone();
        filteredRows.ToList().ForEach(r => filteredTable.ImportRow(r));
        return filteredTable;
    }
```

doesn't works:

```
public DataTable GetTableByDate(DataTable table, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int columnNumber)
    {
        var filteredRows = from row in table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                           where (DateTime)row[columnNumber] > startDate // Error
                           where (DateTime)row[columnNumber] <= endDate select row; // Error
        var filteredTable = table.Clone();
        filteredRows.ToList().ForEach(r => filteredTable.ImportRow(r));
        return filteredTable;
    }
```

[image: error capture]

```
System.InvalidCastException
HResult=0x80004002
Message=La conversión especificada no es válida.
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

invoke (columnNumber is static "1"):

```
    try
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Parse(Session["FCDstartDate"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    grdTest.DataSource = mergeTables.GetTableByDate(dataTable, startDate, 
     startDate.AddDays(14), 1);
    grdTest.DataBind();
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a LINQ bug, chances are the value in the column `rowNumber` isn't a DateTime. Have you tried putting a break point and checking what value is at `row[rowNumber]`?

Comment: What value are you passing for rowNumber?  Shouldn't rowNumber be ColumnNumber?  And if it's ColumnNumber, shouldn't it be ColumnName?

Comment: Yes I tried use breakpoint, sorry is columnNumber and this value should be a "int" well I think so.

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of rowNumber when it doesn't work? Bet it isn't 1.

Comment: I can't understand, the last value is 3! When the value should be one.

Comment: `row[1]` and `row[rowNumber]` both refer to *columns*.  It's unclear what you are trying to do with the rowNumber parameter.

Comment: is the number of the column, and only should be one

Comment: Well. if the value of rowNumber is three, then you are passing that somewhere in your code.  Post that code.  Do you have more than one column that is DateTime you can filter on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164359/discussion-between-jorge-luis-and-larstech).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :

```
DataTable filteredTable = table.AsEnumerable().Where(row =>
                           (row.Field<DateTime>(1) > startDate) && 
                           (row.Field<DateTime>(1) <= endDate)).CopyToDataTable();
```